Cómo recibir los datos de formulario en modal bootstrap dentro de plugin
Estoy creando un plugin, y dentro del mismo necesito un formulario para ingreso de datos en backend. Para eso, uso bootstrap y abro una ventana modal con el formulario. Cuando se ingresan los datos, regresa a la pagina y debo recoger los datos ingresados. Pero no lo hace...
````<form method="post">

              <div class="modal-body">

                      <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="fechaTC" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Fecha</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">    
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" id="fechaTC" style="margin-left:5px" placeholder="Fecha" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="compraTC" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">T. Compra</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">    
                          <input class="form-control" type="any" id="compraTC" style="margin-left:5px" placeholder="0.0000" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label for="ventaTC" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">T. Venta</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">    
                          <input class="form-control" type="any" id="ventaTC" style="margin-left:5px" placeholder="0.0000" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardarTC" aria-labelledby="btnGuardarTC">Guardar Cambios</button>
              </div>
       </form>````

y no logro que ingrese a este código
if(isset($_POST['btnGuardarTC']))
     {
        //estableciendo las tablas y el query
        $tabla    = "{$wpdb->prefix}TipoDeCambio";
        $fechaTC  = $_POST['fechaTC'];
        $compraTC = $_POST['compraTC'];
        $ventaTC  = $_POST['ventaTC'];
        $query = sprintf("insert into $tabla (fecha,tcompra,tventa) values('%s',%f,%f)",$fechaTC, $compraTC, $ventaTC);
        echo $query;

     }
     else echo "no hay retorno";


Debes usar name para pasarlos usando el submitde un form. Es decir, name="fechaTC", ǹame="compraTC", etc

Y funcionó! muchas gracias masterguru!
